# How to merge two not equal multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have two arrays multi-dimensional arrays as given in the JS fiddle. I want to merge it into one in ascending order if the month1 value is same otherwise print as it is

```
    $array1= [0] => Array
            (
                [month1] => January
                [2020cs] => 84
                [2020as] => 500
                [2019cs] => 17
                [2019as] => 500
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [month1] => February
                [2020cs] => 54
                [2020as] => 200
                [2019cs] => 12
                [2019as] => 1000
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (
                [month1] => April
                [2020cs] => 4
                [2020as] => 100
                [2019cs] => 12
                [2019as] => 1400
            )
    
        [3] => Array
            (
                [month1] => November
                [2020cs] => 0
                [2020as] => 0
                [2019cs] => 7
                [2019as] => 200
            )
    )

   
         $array2= [0] => Array
            (
                [month1] => January
                [2020cr] => 13
                [2020ar] => 300
                [2019cr] => 0
                [2019ar] => 0
            )
    
        [2] => Array
            (
                [month1] => March
                [2020cr] => 1
                [2020ar] => 100
                [2019cr] => 0
                [2019ar] => 0
            )
    
        [3] => Array
            (
                [month1] => November
                [2020cr] => 0
                [2020ar] => 0
                [2019cr] => 1
                [2019ar] => 800
            )
    
        [4] => Array
            (
                [month1] => December
                [2020cr] => 0
                [2020ar] => 0
                [2019cr] => 2
                [2019ar] => 500
            )
    
    )
```

I want to merge it as follows

```
$array_merge= [0] => Array
            (
                [month1] => January
                [2020cs] => 84
                [2020as] => 500
                [2019cs] => 17
                [2019as] => 500
                [2020cr] => 13
                [2020ar] => 300
                [2019cr] => 0
                [2019ar] => 0
            )
[1] => Array
            (
                [month1] => February
                [2020cs] => 54
                [2020as] => 200
                [2019cs] => 12
                [2019as] => 1000
            )
[2] => Array
            (
                [month1] => March
                [2020cr] => 1
                [2020ar] => 100
                [2019cr] => 0
                [2019ar] => 0
            )
[3] => Array
            (
                [month1] => April
                [2020cs] => 4
                [2020as] => 100
                [2019cs] => 12
                [2019as] => 1400
            )
 [4] => Array
            (
                [month1] => November
                [2020cs] => 0
                [2020as] => 0
                [2019cs] => 7
                [2019as] => 200
                [2020cr] => 0
                [2020ar] => 0
                [2019cr] => 1
                [2019ar] => 800
            )
[4] => Array
            (
                [month1] => December
                [2020cr] => 0
                [2020ar] => 0
                [2019cr] => 2
                [2019ar] => 500
            )
    
    )
```

I have used array_merge_recursive() also. It also doesn't work. Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the `var_export($array)` function instead of `print_r` when posting the array. Otherwise is almost impossible to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following logic might help you on your way:

1. give each top-level array key a name of month (`rekey()`)
2. merge the two arrays
3. sort the result set (`$result`)

```
<?php

// top-level array from indexed to associative (name of month)
$array1 = rekey($array1);
$array2 = rekey($array2);

function rekey(array $arr = []): array
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $record) {
        $arr[$record['month1']] = $arr[$key]; // indexed to name of month
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    return $arr;
}
// run the merge
$result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);

// clean up double entries key 'month1'
foreach($result as $key => &$value) {
    if(is_array($value['month1'])) $value['month1'] = $value['month1'][0];
}

// prepare result set for sorting
$months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
           'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
foreach($result as $key0 => $value0) {
    foreach($months as $key1 => $value1) {
        if($key0 === $value1) {
            $result[$key1] = $result[$key0]; // set index based on month 0-11
            unset($result[$key0]);
        }
    }
}
ksort($result); // sort
$result = array_values($result); // top-level array back to sequential index
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/4ok0u)